# Need to find the sql table how it is updating

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I stucked in the middle , i have a table in Sql server temp_mec it was stopped updating since jan 14 i couldn't able to find the sql job which is updating is there any way to find which job was updating this table or please provide me any other options which i can find the source of table updation 
Thanks in advance
Regards
Krish

Comment: How do you know that was a sql job? Cannot it being updated by a external app connecting to the DB? Or a by linked server,etc? Anyway you can open SQL Server Agent and peruse the jobs here. Also you can try your luck and see there are specific accounts/permissions to update that table.

Comment: how can we know that which account was used to upadate the table lastly

Comment: You cannot (if you don't implemented it). All you can do is to check what  permissions/accounts are being used now. But it sounds like you got just the default **SA** account doing everything. More it sounds like you are looking for a auditing/logging level is not implemented by default

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    name as 'Job Name',* 
FROM 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps,
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
WHERE 
msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id
AND command like '%temp_mec%'
```

This will return any job that has TSQL Code that contains 'temp_mec'.